# AJAX Call 404'ing on staging server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have AJAX form submission working fine locally. But when pushed to my staging server the process page is 404'ing. I cannot access it directly neither as it 404's but checking on the server and its 100% there with correct permissions too.

The code for the AJAX:

```
$('body').on('submit', '.product-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url : '/wp-content/themes/hinge_client_theme/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : thisForm.serialize(),
        before : $(".error-message").remove(),
        success : function(data) {        
            // removed for question
        },
    });
});
```

That send-form.php is 404ing on the network tab, any ideas whats going on? Working fine locally.

This a WordPress site but not sure if that is whats affecting it since it works locally.

The URL its trying to call on staging is:

```
http://staging.domain.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php
```

Comment: If you right click on the entry in the network tab, and then press open in new tab. Does it take you to the page? If not, /wp-content/ might not be in your root folder.

Comment: 404's if accessing directly too. Can access directly on local so thats why its confusing me.

Comment: Check the path in url : It varies on localhost and on live server in most cases

Comment: Then the path to your file is wrong. Are you sure that the folder wp-content exists in the **root folder** of your website? (So public-html, htdocs)

Comment: This sounds like an issue caused by not developing locally using a Virtual Host that mimics the live environment DocumentRoot. Do you dev using a url like `localhost/project` and run on staging using `example.com`

Comment: Yeah most likely something to do with the structure / the fact its in a subdomain. First time come across this issue in many projects working this  way though. Using mamp pro so access the site using local.domain.com which is just a etc/hosts name to access the folder given.

Comment: If I run 'ls' when SSH'd into where I pull my project on the server I see the main directory like normal. wp-content etc.

Comment: Check ajax request in your browser console. What's the url requested ? The good one ?

Comment: `before : $(".error-message").remove(),` <---WRONG --

Answer (score 0):

You have to use url like this for staging

```
    url : '/staging/wp-content/themes/hinge_client_theme/page-templates/template-parts/template-logic/send-form.php',
```

Because you are in folder "staging".